# matlab.engine, Python2.7, matlab 2018 segfault error

Tags: python-2.7, matlab, segmentation-fault

I am trying to import matlab.engine in my python code. I get the following error:

**import matlab.engine File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/__init__.py", line 62, in module 'MathWorks Technical Support for assistance: %s' % e) EnvironmentError: Please reinstall MATLAB Engine for Python or contact MathWorks Technical Support for assistance: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/local/software/matlab2018/extern/engines/python/dist/matlab/engine/glnxa64/matlabengineforpython2_7.so)**

If I move that "import matlab.engine" to the first line I get the following error:

**Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)**

OS: redhat

python: python.2.7.5 (not installed by anaconda)

matlab: MATLAB2018a

Python path: /usr/bin/python2.7

matlab.engine path: /usr/local/software/matlab2018/extern/engines/python/dist/matlab/engine/glnxa64/matlabengineforpython2_7.so

**What I already tested:**

1. Reinstalling the matlab.engine using the same python as I am compiling
2. renaming the libstdc++.so.6, so the matlab finds the system libstdc++ library
3. Adding the following line to my .bashrc file: alias matlab='LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19 /usr/local/software/matlab2018/bin/matlab -desktop'